# After a query, don't return row with NULL with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI = '2017-04-15' THEN "In Arrival"
    WHEN ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO = '2017-04-15' THEN "In Departure"
    WHEN '2017-04-15' > ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI AND '2017-04-15' < ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO THEN "In House"
END AS BOO_BookingStatus
FROM ___Bookings
```

How can I specific that I do not want the row when `BOO_BookingStatus` == `NULL` ?

Thanks.

Comment: `WHERE BOO_BookingStatus IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to wrap it in another query and define a condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *,
            CASE
                WHEN ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI = '2017-04-15' THEN "In Arrival"
                WHEN ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO = '2017-04-15' THEN "In Departure"
                WHEN '2017-04-15' > ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI
                     AND '2017-04-15' < ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO THEN "In House"
            END AS BOO_BookingStatus
     FROM ___Bookings) AS bookings_query
WHERE bookings_query.BOO_BookingStatus IS NOT NULL;
```

Or to explicit exclude all case where your `CASE` statement would return null:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
           WHEN ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI = '2017-04-15' THEN "In Arrival"
           WHEN ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO = '2017-04-15' THEN "In Departure"
           WHEN '2017-04-15' > ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI
                AND '2017-04-15' < ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO THEN "In House"
       END AS BOO_BookingStatus
FROM ___Bookings
WHERE ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI = '2017-04-15'
    OR ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO = '2017-04-15'
    OR ('2017-04-15' > ___Bookings.BOO_DateCI   
        AND '2017-04-15' < ___Bookings.BOO_DateCO)
```

Comment: Hello, which one of you both solution is the best or fastest ?

Comment: I'd prefer the second one but it depends a lot on you table size and structure. Maybe try both of them and decide then.

Comment: I will take the second one. Thanks.